# Unable to run program via port 443

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I am running a program built on Python. When I am running the program on the Wintel server via port 80 I have no issues. Program name - `TelegramBot-ASN.py`.

1. Port 80
   Running on `http://<IP Address>:80/` (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2. However via port 443 encounter below issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TelegramBot-ASN.py", line 49, in <module>
    app.run(host=strHost, port=strPort, debug=True)
  File "C:\RPA\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\RPA\Applications\Python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 987, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
  socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the error a little, it is seen that the error was thrown while trying to bind the socket.
Usually, a common error in a bind is that the port to be used is already used.
But here is the **getaddrinfo** failed error.
**If you are not given an IP for the host argument in the **app.run** method, give an IP.** (internetwork IP).
Do not give domain names like localhost.

Example : app.run(host="192.168.1.102",

Also find out if 443 was taken by another process.
You can also find it by typing the following command in the powershell.

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 443).OwningProcess
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. The above command returned as below, do i need to install any lib to make it work - please advise.                                                                           C:\>Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 443).OwningProcess
'Get-Process' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Type on PowerShell, not CMD prompt,  change host argument to internetwork IP.

Comment: The machine does not have PowerShell and i do not have access to install it. If any  command (that can be run in cmd) can help please advise.

Comment: I am also running the command with IP Address and not Localhost.

Answer (score 0):

`getaddrinfo failed` means the hostname can't be resolved. Make sure the hostname you used is correct. Also check that there isn't another process listening on port 443.

To check which program is listening on port 443

```
netstat -ano -p tcp |find "443"
```

The command will return output similar to this

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15096
```

To understand which is the program with that pid use the command(obviously use the pid that returned the previous command to you):

```
tasklist |find "15096"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to find the PID using 443. However the find "443" command shows a lot of results (like below almost 140 rows), not sure how to identify the process/file using this PID.  Can you please assist ?                                                                                      System Idle Process       0 Services                   0          4 K
System                           4 Services                   0        136 K
smss.exe                       496 Services                 0      1,264 K

Comment: You must find the row where the port: 443 is specified in the second column (the one after the column that indicates the protocol), that is, next to the word TCP. You will see that only one record with port 443 will exist in that column. If you find nothing in that column, then it means that there is no other process listening on port 443

Comment: Otherwise, as suggested by @Rumira, start the windows powershell and use the command: `Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 443).OwningProcess`. If there is a process using that port it will return the process name to you, otherwise an error will be displayed.

Comment: I could able to get the PID using netstat -ano -p tcp |find "443". But when run the next command C:\>tasklist |find "PID" returned lot of rows with 5 columns. Please advise which column will inform abt the program belonging to that PID.